# Is there a mathematical sign for "or"?

Tags: terminology

Is there a mathematical sign for "**or**"? When I have to explain something in numbers, and I have **two** ways to explain it and I need to separate them by a sign.

Comment: You can use $\vee$. In context: $x^{2}=4$ has solution $x=2\vee -2$.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens I would phrase that as $x = 2 \lor x = -2$.

Comment: Wiki...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logical "or"  is $\vee$; however, unless you are doing mathematical logic like set theory, that symbol is not widely used, because it is usually unnecessary and the work required to understand it outweighs its potential use/time saving.